# What are cats for?

Tags: civ-clicker

A cat [turned up](http://dhmholley.co.uk/civclicker.html). I don't know why it turned up, but I seem to have one now. Does it do anything? How do I get more?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm just going to quote [the civ-clicker's wiki](http://civ-clicker.wikia.com/wiki/Cats) on cat :

> Cats are a type of population, which cannot be created by the player directly. They are not affected by the population limit, nor do they consume food.

About creating more :

> Each time the player creates workers by clicking a button, there is a certain chance that a cat will be created at the same time. It is irrelevant if the button for 1, 10, 100 or 1000 workers is clicked, the chance of creating a cat stays the same.

They influence at this time 2 thing, as **Pest control** :

> The increase in food production will last 10 seconds * number of cats.

And **Warmth of the Companion** :

> Each cat counts as an additional apothecary, but will not be affected by happiness.

You got 3 achievements when having 1, 10 & 100 cats accordingly.

It seems, according again to its wiki, that more features and builds around cat will pop-up.